# Counting a specific table result after executing a SELECT statement

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select, subquery

I am a student-trainee at a certain company. They asked me to do a monitoring system for computer equipment. I made a filter option to filter the results of a table. The filter option contains radio buttons called the "Condition" and "State". The condition is a column that only has values Available, Assigned, For repair, w/ missing part, missing eq, defective, refurbished and Unknown condition. The state is also a column that only has values that are New, Old and Unknown State. These column values are also radio buttons in the filter option. The problem is I wanted to display the quantity of the values beside the radio button labels but I cannot think of a way to count these results as I already used the SELECT statement to display the table result. Is there a way to count the values generated after the execution of the SELECT statement? The select statement happens whenever the user clicks the radio buttons or whenever there are changes in the filter option. I just wanted to count the Available, Assigned, For repair, etc. BTW the allstate, allcondition, and working are just radio buttons and not a column value. Stored inside the $state and $condition variables are the radio button values stored inside a PHP session that is used to filter table results. The filtering using the radio buttons is already working. Below is my code:

```
<?php
 $state=$_SESSION['state'];
 $condition=$_SESSION['condition'];
 ?>

 <span style="margin-left:35px;">STATE</span><br><br>
 <form>
 <input type="radio" name="state" id="state" value="allstate" 
  onchange="javascript:handleRadio(this)" <?php echo $state==='allstate' ? 
  'checked' : '' ?>> All State <br>
  <input type="radio" name="state" id="new" value="new" 
 onchange="javascript:handleRadio(this)" <?php echo $state==='new' ? 
 'checked' : '' ?>> New EQ <br>
<input type="radio" name="state" id="old" value="old" 
onchange="javascript:handleRadio(this)" <?php echo $state==='old' ? 
'checked' : '' ?>> Old EQ <br>
<input type="radio" name="state" id="unknown" value="Unknown state" 
onchange="javascript:handleRadio(this)" <?php echo $state==='Unknown state' 
? 'checked' : '' ?>> Unknown State <br>
</form>

                                         <!--    -->
<form action="" method="POST" class="filters2">
<span style="margin-left:150px;">CONDITION</span><br><br>
<input type="radio" name="condition" value="allcondition" 
onchange="javascript:handleRadiocond(this)" <?php echo 
$condition==='allcondition' ? 'checked' : '' ?>> All Condition <br>
<input type="radio" name="condition" value="working" 
onchange="javascript:handleRadiocond(this)" <?php echo 
$condition==='working' ? 'checked' : '' ?>> Working EQ (1 & 2): <br>
<input type="radio" name="condition" value="Available/Unassigned" 
onchange="javascript:handleRadiocond(this)" <?php echo 
$condition==='Available/Unassigned' ? 'checked' : '' ?>> 
(1)Available/Unassigned EQ:<br>
 <input type="radio" name="condition" value="assigned" 
 onchange="javascript:handleRadiocond(this)" <?php echo 
 $condition==='assigned' ? 'checked' : '' ?>>(2)Assigned EQ:<br>
<input type="radio" name="condition" value="repair" 
onchange="javascript:handleRadiocond(this)" <?php echo $condition==='repair' 
  ? 'checked' : '' ?>> For Repair EQ:<br>
<div class="filters3">
<input type="radio" name="condition" value="missingpart" 
onchange="javascript:handleRadiocond(this)" <?php echo 
$condition==='missingpart' ? 'checked' : '' ?>> W/ Missing Parts EQ: <br>
<input type="radio" name="condition" value="missingeq" 
onchange="javascript:handleRadiocond(this)" <?php echo 
$condition==='missingeq' ? 'checked' : '' ?>> Missing EQ: <br>
<input type="radio" name="condition" value="defective" 
onchange="javascript:handleRadiocond(this)" <?php echo 
 $condition==='defective' ? 'checked' : '' ?>> Defective EQ <br>
<input type="radio" name="condition" value="refurbished" 
onchange="javascript:handleRadiocond(this)" <?php echo 
$condition==='refurbished' ? 'checked' : '' ?>> Refurbished: <br>
<input type="radio" name="condition" value="Unknown condition" 
onchange="javascript:handleRadiocond(this)" <?php echo $condition==='Unknown 
 condition' ? 'checked' : '' ?>> Unknown Condition: <br>
 </div>
 </form>

<?php
if($state=='allstate' && $condition=='allcondition'){
 $sql = (
"SELECT *
 from eq_inv
 left JOIN empl_tbl
    on eq_inv.empl_no=empl_tbl.empl_no
 WHERE eq_state='new'
 OR eq_state='old'
 OR eq_state='Unknown state'
 AND (eq_condition='Available/Unassigned'
   OR eq_condition='assigned'
   OR eq_condition='repair'
   OR eq_condition='missingpart'
   OR eq_condition='missingeq'
   OR eq_condition='refurbished'
   OR eq_condition='Unknown condition')
 ORDER BY empl_firstname
      , empl_lastname
      , middlename  ASC"
  );
}

elseif($state=='allstate' AND ($condition=='Available/Unassigned' OR 
$condition=='assigned' OR   $condition=='repair' OR 
$condition=='missingpart' OR $condition=='mmissingeq' OR 
$condition=='defective' OR $condition=='refurbished' OR $condition=='Unknown 
condition')){
$sql = (
"SELECT *
from eq_inv
left JOIN empl_tbl
  on eq_inv.empl_no=empl_tbl.empl_no
WHERE eq_condition='$condition'
AND (eq_state='new'
  OR eq_state='old'
  OR eq_state='Unknown state')
ORDER BY empl_firstname
  , empl_lastname
  , middlename  ASC"
  );
 }
 elseif($condition=='allcondition' AND ($state=='new' OR $state=='old' OR 
 $state=='Unknown state')){
  $sql = (
"SELECT *
from eq_inv
left JOIN empl_tbl
  on eq_inv.empl_no=empl_tbl.empl_no
  WHERE eq_state='$state'
  AND (eq_condition='Available/Unassigned'
    OR eq_condition='assigned'
    OR eq_condition='repair'
    OR eq_condition='missingpart'
    OR eq_condition='missingeq'
    OR eq_condition='refurbished'
    OR eq_condition='Unknown condition')
  ORDER BY empl_firstname
    , empl_lastname
    , middlename  ASC"
  );
  }
  elseif($condition=='working' AND ($state=='new' OR $state=='old' OR 
  $state=='Unknown state')){
        $sql = (
          "SELECT *
          from eq_inv
          left JOIN empl_tbl
            on eq_inv.empl_no=empl_tbl.empl_no
          WHERE eq_state='$state'
          AND (eq_condition='Available/Unassigned'
            OR eq_condition='assigned')
          ORDER BY empl_firstname
            , empl_lastname
            , middlename  ASC"
          );
        }
       elseif($condition=='working' AND ($state=='allstate')){
                $sql = (
                  "SELECT *
                  from eq_inv
                  left JOIN empl_tbl
                    on eq_inv.empl_no=empl_tbl.empl_no
                  WHERE eq_state='new'
                  OR eq_state='old'
                  OR eq_state='Unknown state'
                  AND (eq_condition='Available/Unassigned'
                    OR eq_condition='assigned')
                  ORDER BY empl_firstname
                    , empl_lastname
                    , middlename  ASC"
                  );
                }
           else{
        $sql = (
      "SELECT *
     from eq_inv
      left JOIN empl_tbl
       on eq_inv.empl_no=empl_tbl.empl_no
       WHERE eq_state='$state'
       AND eq_condition='$condition'
      ORDER BY empl_firstname
    , empl_lastname
    , middlename  ASC"
    );
  }
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
   ?>
      <td>
      <a href="temporarypopup.php"><button>View</button></a>
      </td>
      <td style="font-size:16px;"><STRONG><?php echo $row['eqdesc']; ?> 
      </STRONG></td>
      <td><?php echo $row['eq_inv_id']; ?></td>
      <td style="color:red; font-size:15px;"><strong><a href="timeline.php? emp_no=<?php echo $row['empl_no'];?>" style="color:inherit;"><?php echo 
      $row['empl_firstname']; ?></a></strong></td>
      <td style="color:red; font-size:15px;"><strong><a href="timeline.php? emp_no=<?php echo $row['empl_no'];?>" style="color:inherit;"><?php echo 
       $row['middlename']; ?></a></strong></td>
      <td style="color:red; font-size:15px;"><strong><a href="timeline.php?emp_no=<?php echo $row['empl_no'];?>" style="color:inherit;"><?php echo 
       $row['empl_lastname']; ?></a></strong></td>
      <td><?php echo $row['brand']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['serial_no']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['eq_state']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['eq_condition']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row['curr_equip_loc']; ?></td>
    </tbody>
     <?php
      }

     ?>
```

[image]

Comment: You should look at the `in()` operator in mysql. It will make `eq_condition='Available/Unassigned'
   OR eq_condition='assigned'
   OR eq_condition='repair'
   OR eq_condition='missingpart'
   OR eq_condition='missingeq'
   OR eq_condition='refurbished'
   OR eq_condition='Unknown condition'` a lot easier to read, and add to in the future. Additionally `in_array` in PHP for your `$condition` check will also be easier, `array('Available/Unassigned', 'assigned')`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll keep that in mind

Answer (score 2):

You can use `mysqli_num_rows()` to give you the number of records returned from your query.

```
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
```

Then in your CONDITION form display that value (if it's set) for the condition you ran the query for.

Also just a heads up you have a minor typo in one of your elseif blocks

```
elseif($state=='allstate' AND ($condition=='Available/Unassigned' OR 
$condition=='assigned' OR   $condition=='repair' OR 
$condition=='missingpart' OR $condition=='mmissingeq' OR 
// ...
// Should probably be
elseif($state=='allstate' AND ($condition=='Available/Unassigned' OR 
$condition=='assigned' OR   $condition=='repair' OR 
$condition=='missingpart' OR $condition=='missingeq' OR
```

Comment: But how can I identify and count the rows of a condition category? For example, count the rows which have a condition of "Available/Unassigned" ?

Comment: Well since the State and Condition forms are radio buttons only you can only select 1 for each. So I would use that as my WHERE clause parameters, similar to how you did at the very end of your if blocks for the $sql variable.
Or are you wanting to display the number of rows before the form is submitted?

Comment: I now have an idea. I will use the sessions stored inside the $state and $condition. I forgot to include above that the quantity to display in a condition category will also depend on the state(new, old, or unknown state) but I think I can also use the $state to include it in the where clause to count the, for example, 'Available/Unassigned' using mysqli_num_rows().

Comment: The page is reloaded when the user clicks another radio button similar to facebook search.

Comment: ah ok nice! sounds like you are on your way!